# Create address from multiple strings and separate them by comma

Tags: javascript, angular

let's imagine, I've got 5 strings and any of it can be filled in or just stay empty (it's based on user input)

I wonder how to separate them nice with comma. I feel like this problem have to  be trivial but only idea I found out that will work and is not totally stupid is:

```
// Create a function which return me string of arrays
public getAddress(): string[] {
    let result = [];
    if (this.application.applicant.city) {
        result.push(this.application.applicant.city);
    }
    if (this.application.applicant.postalCode) {
        result.push(this.application.applicant.postalCode);
    }
    if (this.application.applicant.state && this.application.applicant.state.name) {
        result.push(this.application.applicant.state.name);
    }
    return result
}
// Then somewhere in ngOnInit() just call this method:
this.address = this.getAddress();
```

And inside of my tempalte:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of address; let isLast=last">
   {{item}}{{isLast ? '' : ', '}}
</span>
```

or clasic JS way:

```
<span> {{address.join(", ")}} </span>
```

And I still feel like this is overcomplicated. Am I missing some easy solution?
Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 0):

There is a typescript function to **split** a **string**. It also remove the **,**

```
this.addres = this.address.split(', '); // this is now an array instead of a string.
```

**EDIT**

I create a string and but the **newValue** in it the newValue can be anything.

```
let string = '';
if() {
   string = `${string}, ${newValue}`;
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking for splitting string by `, ` but rather create that string.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample solution than yours ,you create the address's string in your method and show it directly in your html template (i think it's more simpler than iterating on the array.. )

in your .ts :

```
address : string ;
// Create a function which return me string of arrays
public getAddress(): string {
    let result = "";
    if (this.application.applicant.city) {
        result.push(this.application.applicant.city+",");
    }
    if (this.application.applicant.postalCode) {
        result.push(this.application.applicant.postalCode+",");
    }
    if (this.application.applicant.state && this.application.applicant.state.name) {
        result.push(this.application.applicant.state.name+",");
    }
    if (result.length !== 0 )
        result.substring(0, result.length-1);

    return result

}
// Then somewhere in ngOnInit() just call this method:
this.address = this.getAddress();
```

in your HTML template :

```
<span>{{address}}</span>
```

Hope it helps :)